# get back the parameter in fulfill function

Tags: solidity, chainlink, api

i have a contract that inherits from **ChainlinkClient** to send requests to an API,
this contract have 3 main functions :

```
function onTokenTransfer(
    address _sender,
    uint256 _fee,
    bytes calldata _data
) public {
    require(_fee >= fee, "NOT ENOUGH FUNDS");
    bytes memory data = _data[4:];
    uint256 _id = abi.decode(data, (uint256));
    requestVolumeData(_id);
}
```

---

```
function requestVolumeData(uint256 _id) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
        jobId,
        address(this),
        this.fulfill.selector
    );

    // do somthing with _id
    req.add(
        "get",
        "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD"
    );
    req.add("path", "RAW,ETH,USD,VOLUME24HOUR"); 
    int256 timesAmount = 10 ** 18;
    req.addInt("times", timesAmount);
    return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
}
```

---

```
function fulfill(
    bytes32 _requestId,
    uint256 _volume
) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
    emit RequestVolume(_requestId, _volume);
    volume = _volume;
}
```

When a user calls my contract using `link.transferAndCall` with an `_id`, the `onTokenTransfer` function calls `requestVolumeData` with the same `_id`, this function make a request to the node and the node returns the requested data to the `fulfill` function .

**My question is :** How can i get the value of the _id used in `requestVolumeData` in my fulfill function ??

My struct and (id=>struct) mapping :

```
struct Collab {
    address promoter;
    address client;
    string apiUrl;
    uint256 amount;

}

mapping(uint256 => Collab) public collabById;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the `_id` into some state variable like:

```
uint256 id;

function requestVolumeData(uint256 _id) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {



    Collab memory collab;

    // You can set the values that you are having 

    collab.apiUrl = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD";
    
    collab.promoter = msg.sender; // Or any other address that goes here

    collab.client = msg.sender; // Or any other address that goes here

    collab.amount = 0; // Setting this 0 for now, you can leave that too because by-default it's 0 only

    id = _id;

    collabById[id] = collab;

    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
        jobId,
        address(this),
        this.fulfill.selector
    );

    // do somthing with _id
    req.add(
        "get",
        "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD"
    );
    req.add("path", "RAW,ETH,USD,VOLUME24HOUR"); 
    int256 timesAmount = 10 ** 18;
    req.addInt("times", timesAmount);
    return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
}
```

Then, in the `fulfill()` function, you can access the latest `_id` value using the `id` state variable:

```
function fulfill(
    bytes32 _requestId,
    uint256 _volume
) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
    emit RequestVolume(_requestId, _volume);
    volume = _volume;
    // You can set the remaining values of the mapping struct here
    collabById[id].amount = volume;
}
```

Comment: i have a mapping (id =>Struct), so i want the user to tap his id so i can get the struct of his infos and work on it, thus i have multiple ids i can't store in single variable .

Comment: @noromeb, yeah to store the ids in the mapping is possible too. Can you please share that part where you're trying to do that ?

Comment: Updated my question above.

Comment: @noromeb, I have updated the answer. Please check if that works for you.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly thank you .

Comment: @noromeb, you're welcome.